# Correct Git workflow for shared feature branch?

Tags: git, workflow, branch

I am trying to figure out the right workflow for this situation:

On the shared repo, we have these branches:

```
-master
-feature
```

The *feature* branch is a **shared** branch, since many developers are working on a new feature together. They are actively pushing their changes to the feature branch.

I'm trying to avoid 'conflict hell' for the day that *feature* finally gets merged back into *master*. Currently, I see some options:

1) **Actively merge *master* into *feature*, and do it often.** However, this is not recommended in the git docs, and I'm starting to see why. When I try this, I seem to fix the same conflicts over and over again.

2) **Use rebase in some way.** I've read up on this, but it looks like it wont work since the *feature* branch is actually shared. All it takes is one developer to do 2 rebases, and other developers could have conflicts from mismatched history.

3) **Turn the *feature* branch into an integration branch,** and have the developers use their own independent feature branches with rebasing to keep things sane.

4) Something completely different?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For a shared branch, I would go with #3, and use it as an "integration" branch to consolidate their work.
The developers would have to use rebase to constantly replay their `private` branch on top of `feature` before merging back their work to `feature`, that way they are:

- solving any merge conflict locally (in their own repo)
- making the final merge (from their `private` branch to `feature`) a trivial one (normally fast-forward)

(as described in ["`git rebase` vs. `merge`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge/804178#804178) answer)

The idea is that, once `feature` branch has to be merged in `master`, no more contribution is accepted on `feature` (the branch is "frozen"), and you can safely rebase it on top of `master` first, or merge it directly to `master`.
And then you start a new `feature` branch (which can actually start in parallel of the previous `feature` branch if needed)

Comment: I think that it's a good rule of thumb that development should usually happen on per-developer branches and shared branches should normally be for integration only.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with rebasing, so I'll ask this question: In this scenario, would the users merge their private branches back into feature only once (and create a new private branch if they need to do more work), or is it safe for them to merge multiple times along with the rebasing they are doing?

Comment: @Ben the idea of rebasing locally is precisely to allow multiple merges: since you never publish your `private` branch, you can rebase it before merging your work to `feature`and pushing it. That being said, if a given development effort is finished on one given `private` branch, it is better to do a new one rather than trying to reuse the existing one. The local history would be clearer.

Comment: That's all well and good, but how do you merge `feature` upstream? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613406/backmerging-a-stitched-up-feature-branch-with-clean-history

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`rerere`](http://progit.org/2010/03/08/rerere.html) to handle the merge conflicts you're seeing multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

*(I'm not too keen on options 1, 2 or 3 so I'm trying to find a better workflow; I'm therefore describing below how I'm thinking of approaching the problem in the hope someone will advise me)*

1. Turn the feature branch in a patch queue using one of the git patch queue tools.
2. Use a separate git repository to version control the patch queue
3. Use the usual git approaches to collaborate on the patch queue.

It might be sensible for people to turn the patch queue back into a feature branch locally.

Answer (score 0):

> **Git Workflow for Feature branch**

The process is follows:-

**First Time:**

```
git pull
git checkout -b sprint-4
git pull origin sprint-4
```

- The above commands will pull all the files from git
- Will make a branch with name sprint-4 on our local machine.
- Will pull the files from server to our sprint-4 branch.

**For every new feature:-**

```
git checkout -b <feature-branch>,  example: git checkout -n fer-181
git push -u origin <local-branch>:<remote-branch>, example git push -u     
origin fer-181:fer-181
```

- Create a remote branch for this local branch on the server.
- Will push files from our local branch to remote branch.

**Daily:(on your feature branch)**

```
git pull
git merge dev
```

- resolve conflicts if any
- do your work for the day

  git push origin

**Feature is complete:**

```
git pull
git merge dev
```

## resolve conflicts if any

```
git checkout dev
git merge <feature-branch>
git push origin dev
```

- The above commands will merge files from main branch in our feature
  branch.
- Resolve conflicts in our feature branch if any.
- Merge the files from feature branch to main branch.

Comment: you'll end up with unusable history