# create a temporary branch name with git

Tags: git, shell, temporary

Slightly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067561/git-create-temporary-integration-branch) I'd like to work with a temporary branch in a shell script.

somewhat along the lines of :

```
cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) &&
git subtree split --prefix=some_subfolder -b temp &&
git push my_remote temp:publication_branch -f
```

Now, I'm not sure what this will do if the branch `temp` already exists, in any case I don't want the result on `my_remote/publication_branch` to depend on that. And I also don't want to modify the branch `temp` (assuming I have it for something unrelated). At best, I would also do a cleanup at the end

```
cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) &&
git subtree split --prefix=some_subfolder -b temp &&
git push my_remote temp:publication_branch -f
git branch -D temp
```

So what I'm looking for is a way to create a temporary branch name that doesn't exist yet, similar to `mktemp`? Is there a git command which can create a temporary branch name?

Comment: I think you're going to have use a UUID of some sort if you are really that paranoid of name collisions, but +1 for a good question.

Comment: I don't think that git has a way to do this, but you could use your command line env to generate a unique temp branch like this bash example: `git branch temp_'date +%H-%M-%S-%N'` (note, its meant to be back-ticks around the 'date...' part

Comment: I'd use max630's answer, and just want to note in a comment that you've come across a common pattern in informatics: the issue of how to name things. We often want a unique, memorable name for a thing, and this becomes very difficult to manage until we add *name spaces*. One way to guarantee a unique name is to have *no* name, as in max630's answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific task you can use split without `-b`, by using this (from its manual):

> After splitting successfully, a single commit id is printed to stdout. This corresponds to the HEAD of the newly created tree, which you can manipulate however you want.

So

```
split_head=`git subtree split --prefix=some_subfolder`
git push my_remote "$split_head":publication_branch -f
```

Comment: I think there might be other use cases where one wants to script with a branch name that doesn't origin in `git subtree split`. Still it fixes my current problem very nicely.