# git filter-tree without branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

As kind of a followup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46152210/4588453) I have a git repository with the following directory structure

```
conferences
├── conferenceA
│   └── proceedings
├── conferenceB
│   └── proceedings
└── conferenceC
    └── proceedings
```

and I want to create a new repository which contains only the content of conferenceA without the proceedings.

So I drafted a shell script in conferenceA which does

```
cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
tmp=$(git subtree split --prefix=conferenceA) 
git filter-branch --index-filter 'rm -rf proceedings' $tmp
git push conferenceAslides $tmp2:master --force
```

Which hase multiple problems:

1. after rewriting the history with filter-branch, new commits are created of which I don't know the hash to fill `$tmp2`
2. `filter-branch` does not accept a hash as argument for me

:

```
pseyfert@computer > git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf proceedings' -- $tmp
Which ref do you want to rewrite?
```

As far as I understood the [git-filter-branch reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), the argument of what to filter, should be the same as for `git rev-list` and there the `$tmp` hash seems fine to me (`git rev-list $tmp` and `git checkout -b test $tmp; git rev-list test` appear to give the same output)

So my question is: How to I use `git filter-branch` without assigning a branch name? Is there a different command I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the rewrite, the next thing your script would do is push the rewritten commit's hash to `master`.  That means you're rewriting the history of `master`, so why not just tell `filter-branch` to rewrite `master`?

To put it another way: the 2nd "problem" isn't a problem; it's the solution to the 1st problem.  Yes, if `filter-branch` let you rewrite an arbitrary SHA-ID, the result would be an unreachable commit whose ID you don't know; so instead `filter-branch` rewrites from a ref and then moves the ref so you can find the rewritten commits by going to the ref.

Comment: hm the problem with a hard coded `master` is, `master` is already used in my private repo containing all conferences and not meant to be overwritten just to create a public one for `conferenceA`. Along those lines 
 the conclusion in [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152210/create-a-temporary-branch-name-with-git?noredirect=1&lq=1) was to avoid possible name collisions by avoiding names alltogether.

Comment: The key words in that answer were "for this specific task"; you didn't need a branch to do that, but you need one to do this.  If your local `master` doesn't track the remote's `master`, you can create a branch that does (something like `refs/heads/conferenceAslides/master` would probably be suitably unambiguous).

Comment: Also... since you're scripting this and so will presumably want to run it more than once, be aware that `filter-branch` will want to create a backup of the ref(s) it rewrites, and a subsequent run will fail unless either (a) you clean up the old backup refs first, or (b) you give it options telling it to clobber the old backup refs.  Personally I find (a) safer. (I try to avoid using, or especially scripting, `force` options.)