# Backmerging a stitched up feature branch with clean history

Tags: git, git-branch

I have this

```
d0 -----
|       \
|        ------ f1  
d1              |   
|               |
|               |
d2------        f2
|       \       |
|        \      |
d3        \     |
|          --- merge
|               |
d4 ---          f3
      \         |
       \        |
        \       |
         ----- merge
                |
                |
                f4
```

No, really. I actually made a repo like this. Note that I had to fix a merge conflict between d3 and f3.

```
C:\dev\git-test> git tree
* 9a169c2 (HEAD, feature) f4
*   1396e5c fixed master -> feature merge conflict
|\
| * 7ececbd (MASTER) d4
| * a2be7eb d3
* | 8c11a80 f3
* |   caa9068 Merge branch 'master' into feature
|\ \
| |/
| * 576ac31 d2
| * fe78786 d1
* | 4e7ac84 f2
* | f3e13dc f1
|/
* 15a0d51 d0
```

I'm regularly merging `master` into `feature` because `feature` is shared, so periodically rebasing `feature` onto `master` would be a nightmare. Each developer has a private copy of `feature` which they keep rebased onto `origin/feature`. To keep `master` and `feature` from diverging I'm stitching in `master` on a regular basis. (Please let me know if there's a better way. I couldn't discern the difference between 1 and 3 in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817967/correct-git-workflow-for-shared-feature-branch).)

Now I want to perform some commands and cause this to happen:

```
d0
|
d1
|
d2
|
d3
|
d4
  \
  f1`
  |
  f2`
  |
  f3`
  |
  f4` <- master
```

This seemed likely:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

The problem is that the merge resolution for that d3/f3 conflict is not remembered. I do have `rerere` turned on. I think the reason for this is that in the first merge we are playing d3 onto f3, and in the rebase we are playing f3 onto d3. How do you handle this problem?

Comment: Not a full answer, but I think you can `reset` to master and then do a `merge --squash`.

Comment: That's way better than anything else I've thought of, so thanks! I'd still rather preserve the individual commits if I Can do so without re-merging everything.